# How do I resolve a 'com4j.dll' error when setting up polling using the Hudson VSS Plugin?

Tags: hudson, visual-sourcesafe, jenkins

When I try to configure my Hudson job to use polling against my Sourcesafe repository, I get the following error :

```
com4j.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: [credit to Allen at hudson-ci.org](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Visual+SourceSafe+Plugin)

What's happening here is that Hudson is trying to use the 32-bit dll from a 64-bit Java process.

To resolve this, simply either configure Hudson to run exclusively using a 32-bit version of the JRE, or just uninstall your 64-bit java runtime and replace it with a 32-bit runtime (don't forget to update your %PATH% values pointing to the JRE!).

Once this is done, the error should be resolved.